# Working with 2 String Sets (Combining them)

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, hashset

I have 2 `Set<String>` with the same amount on Strings in my `OnCreate()`, one `Set<String>` holds messages from multiple users while the other one holds names of those users. I want to join those two `Set<String>` eg. lets say there are 3 messages and 3 user names, I need the first String inside `Set<String>` ("messages") to go with the first String inside the `Set<String>` ("names"), then the second String inside `Set<String>` ("messages") to go with the second String inside `Set<String>`("names").. in that pattern.

I know how to go through all of the `Set<String>`, but I can't figure out how to do it with two to get the result I need. Maybe someone knows a different way? Another example: ( 3 String names) Ivan, Mark, Steve   (3 String messages) Hey!, Whats up with you?, Hi.

I want it join like this: (Ivan sent: Hey!) (Mark sent: Whats up with you?) (Steve sent: Hi.)

This is what I've been doing when I had only one `Set<String>`.

```
SharedPreferences prefMessage = getSharedPreferences(LocalDatabase.SP_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> savedMessages = prefMessage.getStringSet("Message", new HashSet<String>());
   // Set<String> savedNames = prefShouts.getStringSet("Names", new HashSet<String>());


    if(savedMessages!=null) {
       int numMsg = savedMessages.size();
       int i = 0;

       for (String msg : savedMessages) {
           i++;

           newMessage(msg);  //Creates alert Dialog, only sends message, need to include name aka seng newMessage(msg , name)

           if (i == numMsg) {

               savedMessages.clear();
               //savedNames.clear();


           }

       }
   }
```

Comment: `HashSet`s are not sorted nor linked, so you probably want a `LinkedHashSet` (retains insertion order) or a `TreeSet` (sorts naturally or with a given `Comparator`).

Comment: `Set` is no good, use something that persist orders for example `List`. even better, use `JSONObject` where each object holds the sender, message and etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Set` does not have the concept of "first", as sets are unordered collections. You cannot force `SharedPreferences` to somehow maintain the order of values in string-set entries.

You will need to use some other form of data storage rather than a pair of string-set `SharedPreference` entries, such as:

- a file (XML, JSON, etc.)
- a database table (SQLite)
- a plain string `SharedPreference` value with more structured content (XML, JSON, etc.)